# rails and sqlserver encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm  developing an aplication with mysql and sqlserver. sqlserver is used to connect to a legacy table.

here is my definition

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: spvalores_development  
  username: secret
  password: secret
  pool: 5
  host: 192.168.100.35  
  socket: mysql
  port: 3306

sql_server_db:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: SPPokerManager
  dsn: DesaSqlServer
  mode: odbc
  username: sa
  password: master
  encoding: utf8
```

the gems i use:

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'ruby-odbc'
```

this is my model

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name =  "dbo.LOB_CLIENTE"
  self.primary_keys = :CASINO_ID, :CLIENTE_ID
  establish_connection :sql_server_db

  attr_accessible :CASINO_ID, :CLIENTE_ID, :CDNI, :CAPELLIDO, :CNOMBRES,:TIPODOCUMENTO_ID, :CNICKNAME, :CDIRECCION, :CTELEFONO, :CCELULAR, :CEMAIL, :COBSERVACIONES, :CLIENTEPERFIL_ID
  attr_accessible :DFECHAINGRESO, :BIDENTIFICADO, :BACEPTAENVIOSMS, :IFOTO, :COLATIPOPREFERIDA_ID
  attr_accessible :BACTIVO, :CNROJUGADOR, :CSEXO, :DFECHANACIMIENTO, :NACIONALIDAD_ID, :CEMAIL2, :CPATROCINADOR, :CPAISRESIDENCIA, :CPROVINCIARESIDENCIA, :CCIUDADRESIDENCIA
  attr_accessible :DFECHAHORA_CESIONIMAGEN, :BFIRMA, :BJUGADORFRECUENTE, :DFECHAACTUALIZACION

  def as_json(options={})
    nick = self.CNICKNAME.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")
    name = self.CNOMBRES.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8") unless self.CNOMBRES.nil?
    surname = self.CAPELLIDO.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8") unless self.CAPELLIDO.nil?
    {:CLIENTE_ID => self.CLIENTE_ID ,:CNICKNAME => nick ,:CAPELLIDO => surname ,:CNOMBRES => name, :CDNI => self.CDNI, :TIPODOCUMENTO_ID =>  self.TIPODOCUMENTO_ID }
  end 

end
```

i always get errors like this:

```
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

the only way i solved is doing something like this

```
modelinstance.field.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")
```

There are a lot of field on that table. Beside, sure i will need to query other tables like this one.

Looking in the database properties the collation is Modern_Spanish_CI_AS

How i can configure rails to show and save property in the collation Modern_Spanish_CI_AS

Thanks in advance, hope to be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally solve the problem.

I need to use tiny_tds:

here is the explanation:

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds